# getting facebook username and user profile image by email address?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

i want to fetch user profile image and name by using user email address.
i am using **facebook graph api**

in my app user are able to post questions in your wall. and so he will get the responses by other users and we have only their email id so i have problem that how we access profile image and user id by using email address.

right now i am using facebook permission given below:

```
private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {
            "publish_stream", "read_stream", "offline_access" };
```

is there any other permission to access profile info by email address..
please figure out my problem...

Answer (score 1):

For fetching user name and profile pic follow these steps-

1. Put this Permission-

   public static final String[] FACEBOOK_PERMISSIONS = new String[]
      {"publish_stream","email"};
2. Put this code in onComplete(Bundle mBundle) method -

   JSONObject response = Util.parseJson(facebook.request("/me", mBundle, "GET"));
3. Get user name -

   String userName = response.getString("username")

   Now to get URL for profile pic make URL like this-

   https://graph.facebook.com/userName/picture

   For  More details visit [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

Comment: can you please explain what is the value of mBundle ?

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook api doesn't allow you to find a profile given its email address.  But if you have an access token that lets you read a user's wall, you should also be able to use it to obtain the profile image & display name for the author of each wall post.

Comment: It does allow search by email however it is currently broken and Facebook refuses to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You used to be able to search Facebook graph by email address to find a users name and image, but [Facebook broke it and has taken months to fix it.](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/292220680814266)